# website acceleration, loading other web pages resource?

Tags: javascript, optimization, web

I am wondering if such technology exists. In PageA, when the loading is completed, PageA began to load resouces in PageB, which is very likely to be accessed after some time(predict).

If the loading is succeeded, then most of the resource in PageB will be already in cache.
The resource including swf, js, images, etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, some web sites use techniques of prefetching to enhance the loading time of certain web pages. Just think of an photo gallery, slide show, or a series of web pages in general where it is very likely that the next photo/slide/page is viewed as well.

In that case you could prefetch the resources of the next page on the current page to lower the remaining loading time of the next page.

Common techniques are

- the [*prefetch* link relation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Link_prefetching_FAQ) that was introduced by Mozilla (I’m not sure what browsers support this)
- using JavaScript to load images (see [Habax has already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569430/website-acceleration-loading-other-web-pages-resource/4569698#4569698)) or even whole web pages (e.g. hidden frames).

But besides the benefits of lower loading times of subsequent pages you should also be aware that using prefetching can also prefetch resources that are not used (i.e. the assumption that the user does visit the next page is wrong).

Comment: Thanks very much. Is it possible to load javascript and css file individually? And how?

Comment: @Bin Chen: The [‍*Image* technique that Habax mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569430/website-acceleration-loading-other-web-pages-resource/4569698#4569698) should work with any type of resource. Or you use Ajax requests to load that resources.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it exists, some browsers do this, it's called prefetching. *However* it's often *not* done by default in normal browsing (though DNS prefetching often is)...it's mainly used for offline viewing support.

Comment: I mean that we do it in our code, eg) load next page's image when user is viewing current page. Is it common?

Comment: @Bin - Manually in code...no, that's not common at all, and usually not possible, since you can't see content from another domain in JavaScript...so you can only prefetch the site/domain you're currently on.

Answer (score 1):

I always preload images when I'm pretty sure about the next page. You can use this code at the end of your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
preload=new Image();
preload.src="future_image.jpg";
</script>
```